# How to retrieve an output parameter of a stored procedure?

Tags: python, sql, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I'm trying to execute an SQL stored procedure which does some inserts an updates, and I pass a parameter called `lcLogSessionId` to it. During the execution of the procedure this parameter is set to 1 if there are errors, and remains to 0 if everything worked correctly.
In my python script I need to retrieve that value at  the end of the execution of the stored procedure.

This is my code:

```
stored_proc = "Exec [APP].[dataImport] @lcLogSessionId = %s"%(0)
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit = True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(stored_proc)
```

I've tried to fetch the cursor with `row = cursor.fetchone()`, but i  get an  error which says "No results.  Previous SQL was not a query".
Is there a way to get the value of `lcLogSessionId`?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures)?

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyodbc does not currently implement the optional `.callproc()` method, so a workaround is required to retrieve output parameters and return values. For SQL Server that involves an anonymous code block to EXEC the stored procedure and then SELECT the values, e.g.,

```py
sql = """\
DECLARE @out nvarchar(max);
EXEC [dbo].[test_for_pyodbc] @param_in = ?, @param_out = @out OUTPUT;
SELECT @out AS the_output;
"""
params = ("Burma!", )
crsr.execute(sql, params)
rows = crsr.fetchall()
while rows:
    print(rows)
    if crsr.nextset():
        rows = crsr.fetchall()
    else:
        rows = None
```

More details at the pyodbc wiki:

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures#output-parameters-and-return-values